# Regarding ffmpeg in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, scripts, video, ffmpeg, background-process

I need to convert a rtsp and a rtmp link to two different UDP link at the same time using ffmpeg in ubuntu server 22.04. I need to run this as background process only. Also is there any option to start these conversion automatically everytime when iam turning on the server. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of this is giving you trouble? What logging do you need? In what file should it be logged? What should happen to errors if you don't want logging? Should they be discarded? Kept? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Hi. I tried ffmpeg link1 -i -f mpegts outputlink and it is working fine. But I want to run it background only. Also I want to run another ffmpeg command too at the same time for different video conversion. I logged as root user

Comment: Please ***EDIT*** your question and explain what you need. Please answer the questions I asked, put the answers in your question, and also why are you running such a command as root? When should this run? Do you want to launch manually or automatically?

Comment: pls check the question now